# How to find a complement of a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a subspace, which basis:

$(1,1,1,1,...1)$ (its an n dimensional vector that all coordinates are 1)

So lets $W= \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,...1)\}$

I have to find another subspace ($U$) for that:

$W\oplus U=V$ ($V$ is my vector space)

$W \cap U= \{\vec{0}\}$

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can easily check that $(1,0,\cdots,0)$ is not in $W$. This way you will get $n$ different vectors: $(0,1,\cdots,0), \cdots (0,0,\cdots,1)$. You can have only $n-1$ independent Vectors in $U$. So you can choose any of $n-1$ vectors of these $n$ vectors to span $U$.

Comment: So in general, if i have an n dimension vectorspace(V), and a k dimension subspace(W), then every subspace(U) is a good complement for W, if U  spanned by (n-k) vectors which are not in W?

Comment: Provided  those $n-k$ vectors are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $U$ to be $span \{(1,-1,0,...,0),(0,1,-1,...,0),... (0,0...,0,1,-1)\}$. The $n-1$ vectors here together with the given vector form a basis  and any vector in $U$ is independent of $(1,1....,1)$ so $U$ indeed serves the purpose.